Enabling WiFi and EVE2 display leads to trigger WDT
I'm writing a firmware for ESP32-S3 and I have problems using the WiFi with an EVE2 display (NHD-7.0-800480FT-CSXV-CTP). I tried to setup a minimal code to reproduce the issue.
#include <stdio.h>
#include <freertos/FreeRTOS.h>
#include <freertos/task.h>
#include <esp_log.h>
#include <nvs_flash.h>

static const char *TAG = "SYS";

void app_main(void)
{
  esp_err_t ret = nvs_flash_init();
  if (ret == ESP_ERR_NVS_NO_FREE_PAGES || ret == ESP_ERR_NVS_NEW_VERSION_FOUND)
  {
    ESP_ERROR_CHECK(nvs_flash_erase());
    ret = nvs_flash_init();
  }

  //Display_Init();
  Network_Init();

  while (1)
  {
    //Display_Fsm();

    ESP_LOGI(TAG, ".");
    vTaskDelay(pdMS_TO_TICKS(100));
  }
}

here the network functions:
int retry = 0;
EventGroupHandle_t eventGroup;

static void event_handler(void* arg, esp_event_base_t event_base, int32_t event_id, void* event_data)
{
    if (event_base == WIFI_EVENT && event_id == WIFI_EVENT_STA_START) esp_wifi_connect();
    else if (event_base == WIFI_EVENT && event_id == WIFI_EVENT_STA_DISCONNECTED) 
    {
        if (retry < EXAMPLE_ESP_MAXIMUM_RETRY) 
        {
            esp_wifi_connect();
            retry++;
            ESP_LOGI(TAG, "retry to connect to the AP");
        } 
        else 
        {
            xEventGroupSetBits(eventGroup, WIFI_FAIL_BIT);
            ESP_LOGW(TAG,"connect to the AP fail");
        }
    } 
    else if (event_base == IP_EVENT && event_id == IP_EVENT_STA_GOT_IP) 
    {
        ip_event_got_ip_t* event = (ip_event_got_ip_t*) event_data;
        ESP_LOGI(TAG, "got ip:" IPSTR, IP2STR(&event->ip_info.ip));
        retry = 0;
        xEventGroupSetBits(eventGroup, WIFI_CONNECTED_BIT);
    }
}

void Network_Init(void)
{
    ESP_ERROR_CHECK(esp_netif_init());
    eventGroup = xEventGroupCreate();
    ESP_ERROR_CHECK(esp_event_loop_create_default());
    esp_netif_create_default_wifi_sta();

    wifi_init_config_t cfg = WIFI_INIT_CONFIG_DEFAULT();
    ESP_ERROR_CHECK(esp_wifi_init(&cfg));

    esp_event_handler_instance_t instance_any_id;
    esp_event_handler_instance_t instance_got_ip;
    ESP_ERROR_CHECK(esp_event_handler_instance_register(WIFI_EVENT, ESP_EVENT_ANY_ID, &event_handler, NULL, &instance_any_id));
    ESP_ERROR_CHECK(esp_event_handler_instance_register(IP_EVENT, IP_EVENT_STA_GOT_IP, &event_handler, NULL, &instance_got_ip));

    wifi_config_t wifi_config = 
    {
        .sta = 
        {
            .ssid = EXAMPLE_ESP_WIFI_SSID,
            .password = EXAMPLE_ESP_WIFI_PASS,
            .threshold.authmode = WIFI_AUTH_WPA2_PSK,
            //.sae_pwe_h2e = ESP_WIFI_SAE_MODE,
            //.sae_h2e_identifier = EXAMPLE_H2E_IDENTIFIER,
        },
    };
    ESP_ERROR_CHECK(esp_wifi_set_mode(WIFI_MODE_STA));
    ESP_ERROR_CHECK(esp_wifi_set_config(WIFI_IF_STA, &wifi_config));
    ESP_ERROR_CHECK(esp_wifi_start());

    ESP_LOGI(TAG, "wifi_init_sta finished.");
}

here the display functions:
void Display_Init(void)
{
    EVE_init_spi();
    EVE_init();

    // Draw static stuff and save to G-RAM
    EVE_cmd_inflate(MEM_LOGO, LOGO_SMALL, sizeof(LOGO_SMALL)); 
    drawStaticHeader();
    drawStaticPageMain();
    drawStaticPageAdvanced();
}

void Display_Fsm(void)
{
    ESP_LOGI(LOG, "!");
    handleTouch();
    displayListBegin();
    appendFromRam(MEM_DL_HEADER, num_dl_static_header);
    appendFromRam(MEM_DL_PAGE_MAIN, num_dl_static_page_main);
    drawTopBar();
    drawTopButtons();
    drawGloveStatus();
    drawNavigationButtons();
    displayListEnd();
}

The draw functions are quite long, I don't know if I need to post them all.
Anyway, here the description of the issue:

if I run the display functions only all works fine: the display is updated correctly and I see the . and ! debug symbols on the terminal

if I run the network functions only all works fine: I see the . symbol and the WiFi connections debug strings

if I enable both functions, the display is updated few times, then when the WiFi is activated


Here the output:
I (1162) wifi:wifi driver task: 3fcac798, prio:23, stack:3584, core=0
I (1172) wifi:wifi firmware version: 1160f50
I (1172) wifi:wifi certification version: v7.0
I (1172) wifi:config NVS flash: enabled
I (1172) wifi:config nano formating: disabled
I (1172) wifi:Init data frame dynamic rx buffer num: 32
I (1172) wifi:Init static rx mgmt buffer num: 5
I (1172) wifi:Init management short buffer num: 32
I (1172) wifi:Init dynamic tx buffer num: 32
I (1172) wifi:Init static tx FG buffer num: 2
I (1172) wifi:Init static rx buffer size: 1600
I (1172) wifi:Init static rx buffer num: 10
I (1172) wifi:Init dynamic rx buffer num: 32
I (1172) wifi_init: rx ba win: 6
I (1172) wifi_init: tcpip mbox: 32
I (1172) wifi_init: udp mbox: 6
I (1172) wifi_init: tcp mbox: 6
I (1172) wifi_init: tcp tx win: 5760
I (1172) wifi_init: tcp rx win: 5760
I (1172) wifi_init: tcp mss: 1440
I (1172) phy_init: phy_version 620,ec7ec30,Sep  5 2023,13:49:13
I (1212) wifi:mode : sta (24:58:7c:f4:96:30)
I (1212) wifi:enable tsf
I (1212) WIFI: wifi_init_sta finished.
I (1212) TFT: !
I (1222) wifi:new:<6,0>, old:<1,0>, ap:<255,255>, sta:<6,0>, prof:1
I (1222) wifi:state: init -> auth (b0)
I (1222) SYS: .
I (1232) wifi:state: auth -> init (8a0)
I (1232) wifi:new:<6,0>, old:<6,0>, ap:<255,255>, sta:<6,0>, prof:1
I (1232) WIFI: retry to connect to the AP
I (1322) TFT: !
I (1322) SYS: .
I (1422) TFT: !
I (1422) SYS: .
I (1522) TFT: !
I (1522) SYS: .
I (1622) TFT: !
I (1622) SYS: .
I (1722) TFT: !
I (3642) WIFI: retry to connect to the AP
I (3652) wifi:new:<6,0>, old:<6,0>, ap:<255,255>, sta:<6,0>, prof:1
I (3652) wifi:state: init -> auth (b0)
I (3652) wifi:state: auth -> assoc (0)
I (3662) wifi:state: assoc -> run (10)
I (3692) wifi:connected with mark, aid = 4, channel 6, BW20, bssid = 3c:a6:2f:38:34:07
I (3692) wifi:security: WPA2-PSK, phy: bgn, rssi: -72
I (3692) wifi:pm start, type: 1

I (3692) wifi:dp: 1, bi: 102400, li: 3, scale listen interval from 307200 us to 307200 us
I (3692) wifi:set rx beacon pti, rx_bcn_pti: 0, bcn_timeout: 25000, mt_pti: 0, mt_time: 10000
I (3702) wifi:<ba-add>idx:0 (ifx:0, 3c:a6:2f:38:34:07), tid:6, ssn:2, winSize:64
I (3792) wifi:AP's beacon interval = 102400 us, DTIM period = 1
I (4702) esp_netif_handlers: sta ip: 192.168.2.138, mask: 255.255.0.0, gw: 192.168.2.1
I (4702) WIFI: got ip:192.168.2.138
E (6722) task_wdt: Task watchdog got triggered. The following tasks/users did not reset the watchdog in time:
E (6722) task_wdt:  - IDLE0 (CPU 0)
E (6722) task_wdt: Tasks currently running:
E (6722) task_wdt: CPU 0: main
E (6722) task_wdt: CPU 1: IDLE1
E (6722) task_wdt: Print CPU 0 (current core) backtrace


Backtrace: 0x4200CD47:0x3FC9AA60 0x4200D164:0x3FC9AA80 0x4037780D:0x3FC9AAB0 0x4037F248:0x3FCA59D0 0x42009D3B:0x3FCA59F0 0x42009185:0x3FCA5A10 0x42009580:0x3FCA5A30 0x4200840D:0x3FCA5A50 0x4207BD77:0x3FCA5A70 0x4037ED69:0x3FCA5AA0
0x4200cd47: task_wdt_timeout_handling at /home/mark/dev/esp-idf/components/esp_system/task_wdt/task_wdt.c:441
0x4200d164: task_wdt_isr at /home/mark/dev/esp-idf/components/esp_system/task_wdt/task_wdt.c:515
0x4037780d: _xt_lowint1 at /home/mark/dev/esp-idf/components/xtensa/xtensa_vectors.S:1240
0x4037f248: _frxt_dispatch at /home/mark/dev/esp-idf/components/freertos/FreeRTOS-Kernel/portable/xtensa/portasm.S:484
0x42009d3b: EVE_execute_cmd at /home/mark/firmware/components/FT800-FT813-5.x/src/EVE_commands.c:444
0x42009185: displayListBegin at /home/mark/firmware/main/tasks/task_display.c:725
0x42009580: Display_Task at /home/mark/firmware/main/tasks/task_display.c:118
0x4200840d: app_main at /home/mark/firmware/main/main.c:117
0x4207bd77: main_task at /home/mark/dev/esp-idf/components/freertos/app_startup.c:208
0x4037ed69: vPortTaskWrapper at /home/mark/dev/esp-idf/components/freertos/FreeRTOS-Kernel/portable/xtensa/port.c:134

as you can see after few seconds all the debug symbols are not printed anymore and the wdt is triggered because is hangs inside:
void EVE_execute_cmd(void)
{
    while (EVE_busy() != E_OK)
    {
        taskYIELD();
    }
}

it does not depend on the functions I use to draw on the display.
I read the documentation about SPI master and I don't see anything about conflicts with the WiFi.
Here the configuration of the display:
add_definitions(
    -DEVE_CS=GPIO_NUM_14
    -DEVE_PDN=GPIO_NUM_47
    -DEVE_SCK=GPIO_NUM_11
    -DEVE_MISO=GPIO_NUM_12
    -DEVE_MOSI=GPIO_NUM_13
    -DEVE_ROTATE=2
    -DEVE_BACKLIGHT_FREQ=1000
    -DEVE_BACKLIGHT_PWM=10
    -DEVE_NHD_70)

Is there anything that would prevent the use of the WiFi with the SPI master?

About the close vote because I asked multiple questions: I only asked if WiFi and SPI are in conflict and I provided my code. How to improve the question?
